# Layout UILabels with baseline offset

Tags: ios, uilabel, xib

I have a view with labels stacked vertically. The design specification for the view give a vertical offset from the baseline of the text in the top label to the text in the bottom label.

However when I code for this, the size of the top UILabel will always be big enough to accomodate the descender of the top label. So I can only program the offset from the descender, not from the baseline. In the attached picture, red offset is what I want to code for, but I can only code for the green offset. Is there any way that I can get the baseline offset correct either in the xib or through code? I do not want to do this by trial and error, as that would result in the programmed offset not matching the specs.

[image: label offset]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, but easier to show you in a screen shot than to explain it:

[image]

Change "30" to whatever your specified distance is.

Comment: Thanks, guess I'll have to finally learn auto-layout. Is there a way to make this work in non-autolayout mode too? Also I notice that there is still a gap left at the top of the New Change label, is there anyway to take care of it? Will probably accept this answer if there is no other solution coming along.

Comment: Well, if it's really a big deal to have exact control over the layout, why don't you skip UILabel and just lay out the text yourself? That way you have total control. However, that is not the question you asked so it isn't the question I answered. I showed you how to do what you asked to do.

Comment: CoreText is too heavyweight a solution for my expertise level. a few pixels off is not a big deal IMO, but it seems to be the first thing that the designers catch. Looking for an easier solve like the one you have provided. I'll probably ask for a new set of specs with a baseline offset between the two labels instead and set the baseline relation between the two. Thanks for you help.

Comment: If you are iOS 7 only, consider TextKit. It's very easy compared to CoreText. And you can draw directly with it.